# How to make dynamic app settings data accessible to other classes in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I'm using Laravel framework.
On every request, I need to get some settings data from a DB (based on subdomain) and have that data available to the other classes in the app.
I am currently running a middleware to get the data and store it as a session so that it is accessible to other classes.

Question: What is the Laravel best practise for doing the above?

I appreciate this may lead to opinionated answers, however I think it is really important for a developer that wants to work with others to understand best practises and approaches - even if they are up for debate.

Comment: Are you using Eloquent models? [Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships) may help with that.

Comment: Multiple requests to `auth()->user()` only result in one query; it's kept for the length of the request. Thus, if the settings are on the user model, you can just use them directly.

Comment: Sorry ceejayoz, I’ve updated the question, the data is dependant on the subdomain calling it.

Answer (score 2):

As per your requirement you need a single instance through out the application. Check this out [Binding Instances](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/container#binding-instances)

Create you class that fetch settings from DB

```
class SomeGlobalSettingService
{
    public function settings()
    {
        return 'some DB data using DB facade or model whatever';
    }
}
```

Now register the above class in `AppServiceProvider`

```
/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->app->instance(SomeGlobalSettingService::class, new SomeGlobalSettingService());
}
```

Now access this data anywhere in other classes. It will return only a single instance.

```
app(SomeGlobalSettingService::class);
```